# Does a quantum computer exist today?

Tags: experimental-realization, ibm-quantum-devices, google-sycamore

I agree that this may not be an easy question to answer.

But lately, I increasingly come across the fact that many news materials and research papers in the field of quantum technologies say that at the moment there is **no quantum computer** in the world. Instead, they argue that there are only **prototypes of a quantum computer**.

So what do Google, IBM, and other large companies produce?
Are these really just prototypes of a quantum computer?

What about D-Wave computers (like a 2000 qubit quantum computer)?

What characteristics distinguish a **quantum computer** from a **prototype quantum computer**?
And why then do some talk about a quantum computer, while others talk about a prototype of a quantum computer?

Comment: IMO, this is opinion question. What is prototype quantum computer? I doubt a generally accepted definition exists.

Comment: I would reformulate this question to focus on the last part: "*What distinguishes a "quantum computer" from a "prototype quantum computer"?*", to make it less opinion-based. The answer then being: there is no fundamental difference, it's just a matter of whether one considers the device as "paving the way for something else" or as a complete product in and of itself. In other words, the distinction is more a matter of marketing than of science. At the same time, the current title might also be a good target for googlers wondering about this, so I'm not strongly opposed to leaving it be